# Socket.io - Eliminar socket del server después de hacer un socket.disconnect()

Tags: javascript, nodejs, socket.io

Tengo el siguiente problema estoy usando `socket.io` en `nodejs`, y tengo el siguiente código

```
users = {}
ids_disconnect = []

io.of('/example')
    .on('connection', function (socket) {
        var user_id = socket.decoded_token.user;


        if(users[user_id] === undefined){
            users[user_id] = {"socket": socket};
        } else {
            console.log('Se ha connectado otro usuario ' + user_id);
            ids_disconnect.push(users[user_id].socket.id);
            users[user_id].socket.disconnect(true);
            users[user_id] = {"socket": socket};
        }

        console.log("User Connect: " + user_id + " SocketID: " + socket.id);



        //disconnect client
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('User Disconnect ' + user_id);
            if(ids_disconnect.indexOf(socket.id) != -1){
                console.log('Disconnect Force: ' + user_id );                    ids_disconnect.splice(ids_disconnect.indexOf(socket.id),1)
            } else {
                delete users[user_id];
                socket.disconnect(true)
            }
        });
    });
```

};

En users guardo los socket de los usuarios que se van conectando, valido que solo haya un socket por usuario y si hay un socket ya por dicho usuario, desconecto el anterior `users[user_id].socket.disconnect(true)`.

El problema es el siguiente: el socket se desconecta, pero aun existe en el server, es decir cuando recibo data en el server aun existe la instancia de ese socket que desconecte por fuerza.

Answer (score 1):

Creo que el problema que tienes es que una vez desconectas el socket desde el servidor, el cliente, trata de emitir pings a nuestro servidor con tal de reconectarse. Para evitar esto, simplemente, al crear la conexión con el servidor desde el cliente prueba esto :

```
var socket = io.connect('localhost:3000/example', {
    reconnection: false
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Creo que te funcionaría sólo con que mandes a poner **null** la posición del arreglo **users** que estás desconectando.

```
users[user_id] = null;
```

O **undefined**

```
users[user_id] = undefined;
```

Ya que veo que cada vez que vas a iniciar la conexión validas que el socket este definido.

```
if (users[user_id] === undefined) {
     users[user_id] = {"socket": socket};
}
else {
     // .......
}
```

Código completo:

```
users = {}
ids_disconnect = []

io.of('/example')
    .on('connection', function (socket) {
        var user_id = socket.decoded_token.user;


        if(users[user_id] === undefined){
            users[user_id] = {"socket": socket};
        } else {
            console.log('Se ha connectado otro usuario ' + user_id);
            ids_disconnect.push(users[user_id].socket.id);
            users[user_id].socket.disconnect(true);
            users[user_id] = {"socket": socket};
        }

        console.log("User Connect: " + user_id + " SocketID: " + socket.id);



        //disconnect client
        socket.on('disconnect', function () {
            console.log('User Disconnect ' + user_id);
            if(ids_disconnect.indexOf(socket.id) != -1){
                console.log('Disconnect Force: ' + user_id );
                ids_disconnect.splice(ids_disconnect.indexOf(socket.id),1)
            } else {
                delete users[user_id];
                socket.disconnect(true)
                users[user_id] = undefined; // <-------- Está es la linea que agregué
            }
        });
    });
```